# axis2c_http_server can't find axis2.xml

Tags: apache-axis, axis2c

I am trying to use Axis2/c on OS X but when I launch axis2c_http_server, I get the following errors:

```
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [info]  Starting Axis2 HTTP server....
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [info]  Apache Axis2/C version in use : 1.6.0
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [info]  Server port : 9090
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [info]  Repo location : ../
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [info]  Read Timeout : 60000 ms
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [error] dep_engine.c(324) Axis2 Configuration file name not found
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [error] conf_init.c(56) Creating deployment engine failed for repository ../
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [error] http_receiver.c(126) unable to create private configuration contextfor repo path ../
[Fri Mar 16 12:26:19 2012] [error] http_server_main.c(215) Server creation failed: Error code: 18 :: Configuration file cannot be found
```

It seems the server cannot locate the file axis2.xml.
I have put axis2.xml in the repo's root. I have correctly set the environment variable $AXIS2C_HOME because the server write the logs in the right folder.

Here is my repo's structure:

```
antoine@Antoines-MacBook-Air:repo $ pwd
/Users/antoine/Documents/axis2c_test/repo
antoine@Antoines-MacBook-Air:repo $ ll -R
total 16
-rw-r--r--@  1 antoine  staff   5.8K Mar 16 10:06 axis2.xml
drwxr-xr-x  53 antoine  staff   1.8K Mar 16 10:06 lib
drwxr-xr-x   4 antoine  staff   136B Mar 16 12:26 logs
drwxr-xr-x   4 antoine  staff   136B Mar 16 11:14 services

./lib:
total 25816
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   246K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_axiom.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   246K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_axiom.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   1.3M Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_axiom.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   246K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_axiom.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   1.0K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_axiom.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   576K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_engine.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   576K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_engine.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   2.6M Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_engine.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   576K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_engine.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   1.1K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_engine.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   120K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_common.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   120K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_common.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   484K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_common.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   120K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_common.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   1.1K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_common.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    20K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_receiver.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    20K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_receiver.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff    57K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_receiver.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    20K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_receiver.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   1.2K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_receiver.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   112K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_sender.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   112K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_sender.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   355K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_sender.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   112K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_sender.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   1.2K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_http_sender.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    49K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_parser.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    49K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_parser.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   139K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_parser.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    49K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_parser.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   982B Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_parser.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    57K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_xpath.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    57K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_xpath.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   190K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_xpath.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    57K Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_xpath.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   902B Mar 16 10:06 libaxis2_xpath.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   193K Mar 16 10:06 libaxutil.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   193K Mar 16 10:06 libaxutil.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   982K Mar 16 10:06 libaxutil.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   193K Mar 16 10:06 libaxutil.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   867B Mar 16 10:06 libaxutil.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    63K Mar 16 10:06 libguththila.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    63K Mar 16 10:06 libguththila.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   191K Mar 16 10:06 libguththila.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    63K Mar 16 10:06 libguththila.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   923B Mar 16 10:06 libguththila.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   229K Mar 16 10:06 libneethi.0.6.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   229K Mar 16 10:06 libneethi.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   1.4M Mar 16 10:06 libneethi.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   229K Mar 16 10:06 libneethi.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff   1.0K Mar 16 10:06 libneethi.la
drwxr-xr-x  3 antoine  staff   102B Mar 16 10:06 pkgconfig

./lib/pkgconfig:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   256B Mar 16 10:06 axis2c.pc

./logs:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff    12K Mar 16 12:26 axis2.log

./services:
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x  1 antoine  staff    10K Mar 16 12:26 libhello.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 antoine  staff   209B Mar 16 10:06 services.xml
```

Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the client side consumer only, but maybe the solution I have can help you.

In order to run the server you need to set AXIS2C_HOME environment variable to point to the AXIS2C installation.

For the client you don't need to, you just specifiy the location of the axis2.xml file when creating a new instance of axis2c_stub_t type (aka set the client_home parameter.)